# sshfs with gssapi

Tags: ssh, sshfs, kerberos

For my normal login with ssh I have in my `~/.ssh/config` the following lines:

> GSSAPIAuthentication yes
>   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes

... so that if I call `kinit` and get a Kerberos ticket then I can connect with ssh without typing in the password.

How do I make sshfs use the same ticket to mount a remote directory without asking for the password?

(right now I'm getting an error saying `remote host has disconnected`)

And what would an entry for `/etc/fstab` look like for that? Right now I have this:

> sshfs#username@remoteHost: mountpoint fuse comment=sshfs,noauto,users,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,reconnect,transform_symlinks,BatchMode=yes 0 0

BTW: I need to make it use the Kerberos ticket and not my RSA or DSA keys, because that is forbidden on the remote host side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `sshfs ...` in a terminal, in your own user account, then it will use **exactly the same** SSH settings – and Kerberos tickets – as plain `ssh` and `sftp` commands (since it just launches `ssh -s sftp`).

If it does not, try the `-o debug` and/or `-o sshfs_debug` options. Also make sure you're giving the same server hostname to `sshfs`.

I cannot give a good answer for fstab until you get plain `sshfs` working, but you will likely need to `kinit` as root too (but with your own Kerberos principal), or use [k5start](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/k5start.html) to automatically do it on boot.

Comment: using the debug options and running `sshfs` in terminal as you suggested showed that my settings, namely: `GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes` were not used. This was because they were defined for specific host. The trick was to use the host alias I define in my `~/.ssh/config` in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: OK, I have setup my `kerberos` credentials, and `k5start` works fine from the terminal. How do I get it to mount at boot? I cannot think of a way to create a valid line in `fstab`. I think a `systemd` `service` or `mount` file might be the only way to go. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Kartik: Create a service which runs `k5start -K` on boot as a daemon, and make your fstab mount depend on that service. As long as UIDs match sshfs should find the ticket cache. Alternatively, if your OS uses a recent MIT krb5 (Heimdal doesn't have this), putting the keytab at /var/lib/krb5/user/UID/client.keytab would work without k5start.

Comment: @grawity, thanks. I understood some of it, but I have no idea how to make `fstab` depend on that service. Perhaps, I'll post a question and you can answer? My uni uses the MIT krb5, so we can possibly just discuss the second option.

Comment: @grawity, Here is the question: https://superuser.com/q/1354668/520328. Thanks in advance!